# How to eliminate numpy.logspace numeric errors for integer powers of 10 (i.e., 10^n, where n is int)

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.logspace(-4,1,6) to create [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10].

I noticed the numbers generated with numpy.logspace have numeric errors.

print('{:.24f}'.format(np.logspace(-4, 1, 6)[3]))

prints "0.100000000000000005551115" versus "0.1" i expected.

Anyways to eliminate numpy.logspace numeric errors for integer powers of 10 (i.e., 10^n, where n is integer)?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with numpy at all; there simply is no floating-point number with a value of exactly 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: no.

The somewhat longer answer is, that no floating point number with the value `0.1` exists, at least not "exact" (well, it's exact, i.e. within machine precision, for the computer but not in an analytical/mathematical sense)

Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic for further info.